# In a Syllogism with an I Proposition as the conclusion, why must both premises be affirmative?

Tags: logic, syllogism

Source:  *A Concise Introduction to Logic* (12 Ed, 2014), by Patrick J. Hurley

> [p 286:] Rule 1: The Middle Term Must Be Distributed at Least Once.
>
> [p 288:] Rule 4: A Negative Premise Requires a Negative Conclusion,
>   and a Negative Conclusion Requires a Negative Premise.
>
> [p 288:] Rule 5: If Both Premises Are Universal, the Conclusion Cannot
>   Be Particular.
>
> [p 290:] [...] The question remains, however, whether
>   a syllogism’s breaking none of the rules is a *sufficient* condition for validity. In other
>   words, does the fact that a syllogism breaks none of the rules guarantee its validity? The
>   answer to this question is “yes,” but unfortunately there appears to be no quick method
>   for proving this fact. [...] The proof that
>   follows is somewhat tedious, and it proceeds by considering four classes of syllogisms
>   having **A**, **E**, **I**, and **O** propositions for their conclusions. [...]
>
> [p 291:] Next, consider a syllogism having an **I** proposition for its conclusion.
>    By Rule 1, M is distributed in at least one premise,
>   **and by Rule 4, both premises are affirmative.**
>   Further, by Rule 5, both premises cannot be universal. [...]

I do not comprehend only the step bolded above:
How does Rule 4 imply that both premises must be affirmative?

Answer (score 3):

Because **I** is *particular affirmative* and Rule 4 states :

> A Negative Premise Requires a Negative Conclusion,

i.e. if one of the premises is *negative*, also the conclusion is.